# Why won't my counter increment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I've done a bit of C++ programming but I'm new to c#.

I wrote a simple app to count how many times a user clicked a button and then display that count on the button.

On the first click it works, but after that it stays at 1. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int clickcount = 0;
    public virtual void button1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        clickcount++;
        button1.Text = "You clicked me "+clickcount.ToString()+" time";
    }
    public virtual void GreetButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        GreetButton.Text = "Hello "+TextInput.Text;
    }
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see what happens on the second click?

Comment: Web pages are different. They don't have any state, per se; the class is initialized (and `clickcount` to `0` along with it) on every request.

Comment: @JamieKeeling, you REALLY need a debugger to know what happens here? :)

Comment: It works the same way in C++, every time you create a new instance of the class, the constructor runs and initializes the object.  You hope that the Default object lives for ever, it doesn't.  Every page request creates a new one.

Comment: @walther Not myself, the point i'm trying to make is if the user actually tried debugging the page they'd see the behaviour which causes the count to 'reset'.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the count to zero every time the page is created. This:

```
private int clickcount = 0;
```

Is almost the same as this:

```
private int clickcount;

public Default()
{
    clickcount = 0;
}
```

Since the constructor is called every time a page is requested, you'll always reset the value back to zero.

How you solve this depends on what you are trying to count. For example, if you want to count the number of clicks in the current session then you should use a session variable to store the count.

I suggest you read the following webpage to get a good overview of where state can be stored and which type of storage is most suitable for different purposes:

- [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s)

Answer (score 2):

Web pages do not automatically persist data, so the value of `clickcount` is only held in memory until the page is done rendering by the server. The next time you click on the button, your counter is reset to 0. If you want to persist data between postbacks (page loads), you will have to store the data somewhere, such as `Session`, `ViewState` or in a database.

Here is one example, modified from your code:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
    private int clickcount = 0; 
    public virtual void button1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs args) 
    { 
        if (Session["clickcount"] != null)
            clickcount = (int)Session["clickcount"];

        clickcount++; 
        Session["clickcount"] = clickcount;

        button1.Text = "You clicked me "+clickcount.ToString()+" time"; 
    } 
    public virtual void GreetButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args) 
    { 
        GreetButton.Text = "Hello "+TextInput.Text; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

clickcount is going to be set to 0 every time you click the button, because it is initialized on every postback to the value you set (in this case --> 0). If you would make it a private static int, you will see that the values will actually increment.

```
    int counter = 0; <-- gets initialized to 0 on each click
    static int counter1 = 0; <--- gets incremented on each click, so 1,2,3 ...
```

As it has been pointed out in the comments of this answer:
If you plan on actually using the counter, it would be better to use a Session variable to store the amount of times the button has been clicked.

Comment: It would be shared across all users of the web page, and reset when the server is restarted (not per user session), right?

Comment: @sblom is correct, a static variable is shared among all users who would call the page. Not the best approach for a multiuser web page except under only the simplest of use cases.

Comment: @sblom and mgnoonan: im aware of that, but i just tried to answer the OP's question. It would indeed be better (for actual use), as many have posted here already, to use a Session variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not caring about session and other kind of persistence, you could use the VIEWSTATE to keep this value, in a propertie.

Use your code like this, and this will work:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int clickcount 
  {
   get
   {
     if(Viewstate["clickcount"] != null)
     {
      return (int)Viewstate["clickcount"]; //Need to cast the viewstate object in int.
     }
     else
     {
        return 0;
      }
  }
   set
   {
     Viewstate.add("clickcount",value);
   }
  }
    public virtual void button1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        clickcount++;
        button1.Text = "You clicked me "+clickcount.ToString()+" time";
    }
    public virtual void GreetButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        GreetButton.Text = "Hello "+TextInput.Text;
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `clickcount` as a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a simple way to solve this problem

you can add a new label and make visible = false

then the code will be like

```
counter = int.parse(label.text);
counter++;
label.text = counter.ToString();
button.text = "you clicked me "+counter.ToString();
```